# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" in simple update block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-00933, ora-06550

The following Oracle statement:

```
 DECLARE ID NUMBER;
 BEGIN
  UPDATE myusername.terrainMap 
  SET playerID = :playerID,tileLayout = :tileLayout 
  WHERE ID = :ID
 END;
```

Gives me the following error:

```
ORA-06550: line 6, column 15:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 3, column 19:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 6, column 18:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
   null pragma raise return select update while with
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted>
```

I am pretty much at a loss. This appears to be a rather simple statement. If it helps any, I had a similar statement that performed an INSERT which used to work, but today has been giving me the same message.

Comment: Are you running this in SQLPlus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a semi-colon after `where id=:id`

Comment: @rageingnonsense : no problem.  I was wondering if you copy/pasted or if the missing semi-colon was an artifact of retyping the code.

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of problems here:

1. Missing semi-colon (as MJB saw)
2. `:ID` refers to an in-bound variable, so your local declaration (`DECLARE ID NUMBER;`) is not being used.
3. You're using a variable name which (apparently) is the same name as a colum in your table. If you try to use your local `ID` variable, the query will still not use it unless you use a block label.

That said, it looks like you're sending ID in as a bind variable anyway, so it's more likely that you should just remove the declaration from the block.

Comment: That's why I asked whether this was in SQLPlus.  I could not understand how his bind vars were being used.  And I think perhaps this is **not** really what he is running -- it is a test version of code he thought should run.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous you have to prevent spaces between equal operation ,:,and the value 
like this:

```
SQL> BEGIN  
2    IF x > y THEN high := x; END IF;  -- correct

3    IF x > y THEN high := x; ENDIF;   -- incorrect

4  END;

5  /

END;
```

```
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
if
```

visit the website to read more....
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS002